Symfony programmatically register excluded service definition / modify existing service definition
Previously, prior to Symfony 6.2, it was possible to dynamically register classes from the user's src directory within a Symfony Bundle. This was achieved by leveraging the applications services.yaml file to exclude certain classes from being loaded. However, changes introduced in Symfony 6.2 have rendered this approach ineffective.
Previous Behavior (Pre-Symfony 6.2):
In Symfony versions before 6.2, registering classes within a Symfony Bundle could be accomplished as follows:
class MyExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        $classes = ['App\Handlers\UserClass'];

        foreach ($classes as $class) {
            $container->register($class)
                ->setAutowired(true)
                ->addTag('messenger.message_handler', ['bus' => 'my.bus']);
        }
    }
}

And in the applications services.yaml say
  App\:
    resource: '../src/'
    exclude:
      - '../src/Kernel.php'
      - '../src/Handlers/*'

This would then result in the Class to be registered as definition in the ContainerBuilder.
Since Symfony 6.2 this is not possible anymore due to this change:
#46279
In the Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/FileLoader.php/LoaderFileLoader.php the following was added...
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.2/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/FileLoader.php#L251
This results in classes to be added to the definitions even if the resource is excluded.
My Bundle will register the services correctly still, but at
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.2/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php#L91
It gets overwritten again...
Is it not possible to do this anymore? the only workaround I have found is not mentioning the class at all in the services.yaml so it doesn't get added as a "container.excluded" definition.
Basically I need to overwrite an existing excluded definition or I need to modify an existing definition. How can I accomplish this?

I don't know if it would solve your problem, you may try registerForAutoconfiguration instead of register. And also what about removing the runtime tagging in MyExtension::load and implementing tagging of your handlers in the service configuration? See here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html
